# How to balance the equation for the reaction of aluminum bicarbonate and hydrochloric acid?

Tags: acid-base, stoichiometry

Here's what I have to balance:

> Solid **aluminum bicarbonate** and **hydrochloric  acid** combine to form an **aluminum chloride solution** and **carbonic acid**.

Or in an equation form:

$$\ce{\text{__ } Al(HCO3)3 + \text{__ } HCl -> \text{__ } AlCl3 + \text{__ } H2CO3}$$

*Side Note:*

$\ce{Al}$ has a charge of $3+$ and $\ce{(HCO3)}$ has a charge of $1-$. To balance the ionic compound we have to change it to: $\ce{Al(HCO3)3}$.

*The underscores before each compound in the chemical equation are just there for number values we can input in order to balance the equation.*

My question is: what would be the reactants and products in this chemical equation? Would $\ce{HCO3}$ as a whole compound be a reactant itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properly balanced equation is:

$\ce{\text{}Al(HCO_3)_3 + \text{3 }HCl \bond{->} \text{ }AlCl3 + \text{3 }H_{2}CO_{3} } $

Comment: This is a homework question. Please avoid providing the answer directly.

Answer (score -2):

> *My question is... what would be the reactants and products in this chemical equation?*

You give the equation, you just need to balance it.

> *Would HCO3 as a whole compound be a reactant itself?*

No, $\ce{HCO3^-}$ is an anion.